# How can I loop on all items where a certain field is not empty?

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I want to loop over all items in a collection that have a certain field set (not empty). I tried this:

```
{% assign papers_with_demos=site.data.papers | where:"demo", not blank %}
{% if papers_with_demos.size > 0 %}
   <h2>demos</h2>
   {% for paper in papers_with_demos %}]
   ... 
   {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

but it does not work; all papers are returned.

My goal is that the heading "demos" will be shown, only if there is one or more paper with a demo.

Answer (score 0):

If papers are being returned, you must be using data files. If a value is empty for a particular key in a data file it will return false. So you could check the data key with a forloop like:

```
{% for paper in site.data.papers %}
  {% if paper.demo %}
  something
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

You'll find more info in the Data Files section of the Jekyll documentation.

Updated in response to your reply:

```
{% for item in site.data.items %}
  {% if item.random %}
  {% assign random-val = item.random %}
    {% if random-val %}
    <p>true</p>
    {% endif %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

This will return true if inside items.yml, you have - random: true, nothing if empty.

Comment: OK, I know I can check this with a "for" loop, but, I would like to know in advance if there are any papers with demos. See the updated question.

Comment: My goal is that the heading "<h2>demos</h2>" will be shown, only if there is one or more paper with a demo. If I check the condition during the loop, I cannot know in advance whether there will be any papers with demos, so I may print the heading even though it is not needed...

Comment: Nothing is printed when the value is empty in the updated example I showed.